# string object is unable to Deserialize into specific object C#

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net, deserialization

1. Serialize data in string format

```
string data = "{\"VerifyOTPResult\":{\"ReturnCode\":\"200\",\"ReturnMsg\":\"Invalid OTP.\",\"Data\":{\"BrokerName\":null,\"ErrorMsg\":null,\"Id\":null,\"IsValidUser\":false,\"RoleName\":null}}}";
```

2. Object Class

```
public class VerifyOTPResult {
  public string ReturnCode { get; set; }
  public string ReturnMsg { get; set; }
  public ValidateUserResult Data { get; set; }
}

public class ValidateUserResult {
  public string Id { get; set; }
  public bool IsValidUser { get; set; }
  public string BrokerName { get; set; }        
  public string RoleName { get; set; }
  public string ErrorMsg { get; set; }
}
```

3. Using Newtonsoft.Json Assembly for DeserializeObject
   Try 1:

```
var decRes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VerifyOTPResult>(content);
```

**OUTPUT**
Getting null in each property except int property

Try 2:

```
var decRes1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{
    "VerifyOTPResult": {
        "ReturnCode": "200",
        "ReturnMsg": "Invalid OTP.",
        "Status": null,
        "CurrentPage": 0,
        "Data": {
            "BrokerName": null,
            "ErrorMsg": null,
            "Id": null,
            "IsValidUser": false,
            "RoleName": null
        }
    }
}
```

I'm unable to DeserializeObject. How to convert it into my object class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON includes `VerifyOTPResult` but is actually a *different* object with a `VerifyOTPResult` property. You should deserialize to some wrapper class (i.e. `VerifyOTPResultResponse`)

```
void Main()
{
    string data = "{\"VerifyOTPResult\":{\"ReturnCode\":\"200\",\"ReturnMsg\":\"Invalid OTP.\",\"Data\":{\"BrokerName\":null,\"ErrorMsg\":null,\"Id\":null,\"IsValidUser\":false,\"RoleName\":null}}}";

    var decRes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VerifyOTPResultResponse>(data);

    Console.WriteLine(decRes.VerifyOTPResult.ReturnCode);
    Console.WriteLine(decRes.VerifyOTPResult.ReturnMsg);

    // Output:
    // 200
    // Invalid OTP.
}

public class VerifyOTPResultResponse
{
    public VerifyOTPResult VerifyOTPResult { get; set; }
}

public class VerifyOTPResult
{
    public string ReturnCode { get; set; }
    public string ReturnMsg { get; set; }
    public ValidateUserResult Data { get; set; }
}

public class ValidateUserResult
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsValidUser { get; set; }
    public string BrokerName { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMsg { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo might as well try `serializer.Deserialize<MyObj>(str);` for e.g `var result=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<yourObj>>(jsonString);`